# Links to sections of same page in asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm writing some text that will be converted to HTML, as a long single page.

Can't figure out how to make links to sections as in HTML using `#some-id`, so that a user when clicking it will go up or down the web page to

```
<h2 id="some-id">Section A</h2>
<p>Lot's of lines</p>
<a href="#some-id">Go to section</a>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

What you're referring to is called an "internal cross reference".

The markup for an internal cross reference is:

```
<<id,caption>>
```

where `id` is an element on the page that has an identifier, typically a title, and `caption` is optional text that should appear in the link.

You can link to titles that have auto-generated ids, but the formation of the ids could vary based on the attributes `idprefix` and (for Asciidoctor) `idseparator`. The default is to make the title text lowercase, prefix with an underscore, and replace spaces and other punctuation with underscores. The id for the title "Let's make a game!" would be `_lets_make_a_game`.

It is often better for you to specify your own id that will remain stable even if you edit the text of a title. You can do so with:

```
[[id,label]]
```

where `id` is the identifier you want to specify, and `label` is the optional, default label that may be used for the cross reference (if the cross reference itself doesn't specify a `caption`).

If the element that your cross reference points to is a title, you can omit the caption and the label, and the link will use the title's text as its own text.

For Asciidoc, see: http://asciidoc.org/userguide.html#_internal_cross_references

For Asciidoctor, see: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#internal-cross-references

**Usage Example:**

This is how we assign an ID:

```
== Debug Running Pods [[debug_running_pods]]
```

Refer to an ID:

```
<<debug_running_pods>>
```

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use the `link:` macro. Here's an example from one of my Asciidoctor docs:

```
link:#_explore_the_public_directory[17.4. Explore the `public` directory]
```

Info about this is in https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#url. Here's an excerpt from the relevant part:

> When a URL does not start with one of the common schemes, or the URL is not surrounded by word boundaries, you must use the link macro.